# Automatic complete scrolling of sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a single webpage with 4 sections. If a user scrolls halfway through the first section, he sees the lower half of the 1st section & the upper half of the 2nd section.

How do I make the 2nd section automatically scroll up completely (so that break between the two sections isn't seen) when the user does this ?

Comment: Please post your current html, css and javascript code.

Comment: I haven't yet coded anything in regards to this. I was wondering if there is a plug-in that I could use.

Comment: [fullPage.j.s](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
   if($(this).scrollTop() > /* enter amount of how far the second div is here */){
     $("#div-one").slideUp();
     $("#div-two").slideDown(); 
   }

});
```

And use `else if` to continue this pattern.